# How could code and compile Matlab mex files over Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, matlab, compilation, mex

I want to code and build Matlab mex files on Eclipse IDE. How could I do to include mex compiler as one of the c++/c compilers and build the mex code I have with that compiler on Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the tutorial of http://ngoonee.xanga.com/664222870/compiling-mexw32-mex-for-windows-files-using-eclipse-cdt-ide-mingw-gcc-compiler/

Works for me!

Comment: The link is dead. Probably it will be similar for what should be done in Visual Studio - https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-mex-files-with-the-microsoft-visual-c-ide.html. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611538/how-to-compile-a-mex-file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to say but I'll explain how mex helped me.

1. Mex is - Matlab Executable this you'd be using to create the functions similar to Matlab functions Ex: function varargout = foo(varargin). This foo will be your foo.c or foo.cpp.
2. The foo.c or cpp is compiled with the well known C/C++ Compilers mentioned here -http://www.mathworks.in/support/compilers/R2012a/win64.html
3. This generates a foo.mexw32 or foo.mexw64 in Windows and you can call it like a Matlab Function.
4. What you can do is write a code in Eclipse using the C compiler it has get it execute and port it to mex functions easily. Select the compilers from mex -setup

I found this tutorial extremely helpful :
[Mex Tutorial](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ee264/Fall11/cmex.pdf)

and I doubt there is something call "Mex compiler" atleast I've not come across.

Comment: There is a way to generate MEX files from IDE and not MATLAB itself.